# sphinx import parent dir rst file?

Tags: python-sphinx

I need to create one sphinx project for each module,

and each module share some common rsts, like company info, license, etc.

My project tree is like this:

```
./conf.py
./index.rst
./intro.rst
./about.rst

./device1/conf.py
./device1/index.rst
```

I write this in ./device1/index.rst, and it is not worked, how could I import parent rst files?

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   ../intro
   ../about
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
.. include:: ../intro.rst
```

but it will include all the texts...
maybe it is the only way?

Comment: Check out [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17217041/1398841) for a slightly more verbose answer.

Comment: To include only part of the README.rst: https://muffinresearch.co.uk/selectively-including-parts-readme-rst-in-your-docs/

Answer (score 0):

I personally couldn't figure out how to modify the source search path, so I ended up modifying the make file to create symlinks for all `*.rst` files in the sphinx build directory.

```
foreach f ( `\ls OTHER_DIR | egrep '.rst$$'` ) \
    ln -s -f $$f BUILD_DIR \
end
```

(This presumes you're using Linux/Unix.)