# Can sphinx link to documents that are not located in directories below the root document?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, symlink, toctree

I am using Sphinx to document a non-Python project.  I want to distribute `./doc` folders in each submodule, containing `submodule_name.rst` files to document that module.  I then want to suck those files into the master hierarchy to create a spec for the entire design.

I.e.:

```
Project
  docs
    spec
      project_spec.rst
      conf.py
  modules
    module1
      docs
        module1.rst
      src
    module2
      docs
        module2.rst
      src
```

I attempted to include files in the master `project_spec.rst` document toctree like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   :maxdepth: 2

   Module 1 <../../modules/module1/docs/module1>
```

However this error message results:

> WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'modules/module1/docs/module1'

Is it not possible to use `../` in a document path somehow?

Update: Added conf.py location

Update:
Other than the include trick below, this is still (2019) not possible. There is an open issue that keeps getting pushed forward: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/701

Comment: Do you need to add the `.rst` extension to the line `Module 1 <../../modules/module1/docs/module1>`?

Comment: I don't think so because in the [Sphinx Docs](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/concepts.html): Since the reST source files can have different extensions (some people like .txt, some like .rst – the extension can be configured with source_suffix) and different OSes have different path separators, Sphinx abstracts them: all “document names” are relative to the source directory, the extension is stripped, and path separators are converted to slashes.

Comment: OK, just a guess! So I presume that `source_suffix` is set to `.rst` in your `conf.py` configuration file. Also, where is this file in your directory hierarchy, since it seems that all paths are relative to this file?

Comment: Yes, `source_suffix` is set to `.rst` and the `conf.py` is in the same folder as the `project_spec.rst` file.

Comment: Did you find a solution at the present date?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Yes, you can!

In lieu of a symlink (which won't work on Windows), create a stub document that has nothing in it but a `.. include::` directive.

I ran into this trying to link to a README file that was in the top of the source tree.  I put the following in a file called `readme_link.rst`:

```
.. include:: ../README
```

Then in `index.rst`, I made the toctree look like:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   readme_link
   other_stuff
```

And now I have a link to my release notes on my index page.

Thanks to http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2010/12/08/include-external-in-sphinx.html for the suggestion

Comment: It the README has images or similar that have relative paths that aren't valid within the directory index.rst is in, how do you handle it?  I get 'image file not readable' errors.

Comment: Yes, you can also do that in Unix with symlinks.  You can create a link with the same name as the docs-folder (ie `docs`) that links to current-dir('.').  Then you can use :download:`docs\foo.rst` and this would work for fileswithin the `docs` folder or it's parent.

Comment: This works for me. I think this should be the accepted answer, as the solution seems cleaner and more portable, than the symlink solution.

Comment: I just ended up back here and accepted this answer, thanks! Not sure about the images, but you can always copy them in the conf.py.

Comment: I needed to use `.. include:: ../readme.rst` including the extension.

Comment: This is only a partial solution to symlinks since the include directive doesn't resolve relative paths from the original document. I needed to symlink my images folder from the other directory

Comment: To include only part of the README.rst: https://muffinresearch.co.uk/selectively-including-parts-readme-rst-in-your-docs/

Comment: I got "doesn't have a title" as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079655/cannot-get-toctree-in-sphinx-to-show-link ; so I had to add a title above the include directive (and remove the same title from the pointed-to README.rst, to avoid redundancy)

Comment: I had to add the `.md` file extension in the `include` directive to make it work.

Comment: @PierreThibault That indeed includes the `.md` document's contents, but it renders it as `.rst`, not as Markdown. Don't know how to solve that though.

Comment: @NumesSanguis I use recommonmark. See: https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @NumesSanguis Here is the solution: https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#autostructify

Answer (score 15):

It seems that the answer is no, the documents listed in the toc-tree must reside within the [source directory](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/glossary.html#term-source-directory), that is, the directory containing your [master document](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/glossary.html#term-master-document) and `conf.py` (and any subdirectories).

From the [sphinx-dev mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sphinx.devel/4237):

> At STScI, we write documentation for individual projects in Sphinx, and then also produce a "master document" that includes (using toctree) a number of these other project-specific documents.  To do this, we create symlinks in the master document's doc source directory to the projects' doc source directories, since toctree really doesn't seem to want to include files outside of the doc source tree.

So rather than copying files using `shutil` you could try adding symlinks to all of your modules in the `Project/docs/spec` directory. If you create a symlink to `Project/modules` you would then reference these files in your toc-tree simply as `modules/module1/docs/module1` etc.

Comment: That's too bad.  One of the advantages I see in trying to switch from Word docs to Sphinx is that you can import a reusable hardware module into your project and just include it's documentation in the master documentation for the design.  I would use symlinks but alas I am on windows.

Comment: For posterity, I tried adding the submodule doc folder to the `sys.path` in the conf.py but that didn't worky.

Comment: @mc_electron For symlinks on Windows, use the mklink command.

Answer (score 10):

In conf.py, add the relative paths to system using sys.path and os.path

For example:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../Directory1'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../Directory2'))
```

Then use your index.rst as usual, referencing the rst files in the same directory. So in my index.rst in my local Sphinx folder:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   Package1 <package1.rst>
   Package2 <package2.rst>
   Package3 <package3.rst>
```

Then in package1.rst, you should be able to just reference the relative packages normally.

```
Package1 package
=====================

Submodules
----------

Submodule1 module
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: file_within_directory_1
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

Submodule1 module
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: file_within_directory_2
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: Is this new behavior? What version was it added in?

Comment: Would be great if further described to inform beginners. For example, what is `Package1`? Is that first `path` specified using `sys.path.insert`? Or, is there a tutorial somewhere? I can't seem to find the relevant doc.

Comment: ```Package1``` is a named entry so that the TOC shows "Package1" as the title of the section.

Comment: This allows you to autodoc Python modules in another directory, but it doesn't allow you to include RST files in another directory.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my quite similar problem with the difference I wanted to include an external jupyter notebook. I had installed nbsphinx but I couldn't get it to work.
**What did not work:**

1. I had the directory I wanted to include the root in the path:

   conf.py :

   `import os
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(...`
2. Using the `.. include:: directive` the file was included in the documentation but as is.

Finally what **solved** the problem was installing package [nbsphinx-link](https://github.com/vidartf/nbsphinx-link)

Comment: Also important comment. Although the name has the nb. It is not only for notebooks but also works for rst files in general.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is in essence the @Dan Menes, but for Myst parser instead of reStructured.

I would prefer to add this as a comment to @Dan Menes answer as it belongs there, but comments do not allow me to do the formatting, the Myst syntax is sensitive to newlines and the comments are limited in characters. So I'm posting it as a separate answer, even when it's related to an existing answer.

To do include in the Myst you have to format it slightly differently:

````
```{include} ../main/post_installation_windows.md
```
````

It can wrap itself to do the reStructured markup too (which then included file will be treated as it's written in restructured):

````
```{eval-rst}
.. include:: snippets/include-rst.rst
```
````

However, using the native Myst syntax is easier. And it has better features, for example, just including the file will not resolve correctly any references inside the included file, while include-literal should:

````
```{include-literal} ../../example.md
:language: md
```
````

As you might discover that including a simple document is ok, but then including a complex document with many references will cause more headaches, so I would recommend the experimental `include-literal` (from version 0.12.7)

Reference:
https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/howto.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution, if it's really impossible to use relative links that back up `../` is that I could use `shutil` to copy the files into the spec folder tree in the `conf.py` for the spec, but I'd rather not have multiple copies unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to configure sphinx to have only the index.rst file in the root and the all the other sphinx stuff in Project/docs:

For windows I moved all sphinx files and dirs (except index.rst) into docs/ and changed:

`docs/make.bat`: Change

```
set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-d %BUILDDIR%/doctrees %SPHINXOPTS%  .
```

to

```
set ALLSPHINXOPTS=-d %BUILDDIR%/doctrees %SPHINXOPTS%  -c . ..
```

`docs/conf.py`: Add

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Comment: Thanks! That configuration works just well for me when having multiple related packages 
 in one repository, referenced from the same documentation.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate technique which does not require the creation of stub files is to use [absolute references](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html?highlight=toctree#directive-toctree) (starting with `/`) within your toctree root, and setting the source directory to the lowest common ancestor when calling `sphinx-build`. Example directory layout:

```
/path/to/common/ancestor
├── a
│   └── foo.rst
├── b
│   ├── bar.rst
│   ├── x
│   │   └── index.rst
│   └── y
│       └── boz.rst
└── c
    └── baz.rst
```

And `b/x/index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   /a/foo
   /b/bar
   /b/y/boz
   /c/baz
```

And your `sphinx-build` command might look like this:

```
sphinx-build -c <confdir> -b html -D masterdoc=b/x/index /path/to/common/ancestor <outdir>
```

I tested this with sphinx `3.0.2`.

Comment: One drawback of this technique is that the main output document is not `./index.html` but `./b/x/index.html` in your output directory.

Comment: Changed in sphinx version 4.0: master_doc to root_doc. Use `-D root_doc=b/x/index`.