# Cannot Get TOCTREE in Sphinx to Show Link

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I am new to Sphinx. I tried out the tutorial but I failed to generate the link in the contents. The error that I got

```
C:\Users\mhaikalm\sphinxtest\source\index.rst:11: WARNING: toctree contains refe
rence to document 'intro' that doesn't have a title: no link will be generated
C:\Users\mhaikalm\sphinxtest\source\index.rst:11: WARNING: toctree contains refe
rence to document 'zuhdi' that doesn't have a title: no link will be generated
writing additional files... (0 module code pages) genindex search
copying static files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 3 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

I have created `zuhdi.rst` and `intro.rst` in the same directory as `index.rst`. How can I put title to the documents?

For your information, my index.rst contains these lines:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   intro
   zuhdi
```

Do the documents must exist for me to put the links in the toctree? The `intro.rst` and `zuhdi.rst` is just an empty file.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are getting this error because you don't have a title in `intro.rst`.
In order to fix this, add a title to `intro.rst`. Suppose you want your title to be `My Title`, then the title can be added by making the following two lines the first lines of `intro.rst`:

```
My Title
*********
```

Note that you must have enough `*` characters to completely underline your title, else you will get another error about a malformed title or underlining thereof.

Comment: My Title
======= 
will do as well

Comment: It's weird that a simple `#` for H1 output isn't recognized as a title.

Comment: if youre using markdown file instead of rst, then use `pip install myst-parser` and add the `myst-parser` to your extensions in conf.py. then you wont need to add such a title with asterisks to your markdown file.