# Sphinx - Relative links in included file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx to document a C++ project. I have a `readme` in the `src` folder and a full-fledged help website for publishing to [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/) in `docs` folder generated using [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/). I want to reuse the `readme` in my `src` folder. The `readme` includes the code in `src` folder (using `literalinclude` directive).

The project has the following structure:

```
project
  src
    algo.cpp
    readme.rst
    CMakeLists.txt
 docs
    source
       index.rst
       conf.py
       code_link.rst
    build
    Makefile
```

Following advise in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199233/can-sphinx-link-to-documents-that-are-not-located-in-directories-below-the-root) I was able to link my `index` with my `readme` but the path to the code file in the `readme` is now relative to the `docs`. Thus the `readme` no longer renders independently on its own defeating idea of reuse.

Is there a way to have links in included file relative to included file?

Comment: As you mention readthedocs.org, I assume your project is open source. Could you provide a link to the source code?