# Organise .rst files for sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm putting together some user guides using Sphinx. However, there are a number of `.rst` files and it's getting quite difficult to keep track of them when they are all in the main folder along with `index.rst`.

I'd like to organize them into folders like so. But then, the `make html` command results in warnings saying it can't find all those .rst files tucked away within folders.

How can I organise my `.rst` files?

```
index.rst
  Docs
     new_starter.rst
     subject_guides.rst
  New starter
     first_week.rst
     second_week.rst
  Subject guides
     stress.rst
     aerodynamics.rst
     data_science.rst
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199233/can-sphinx-link-to-documents-that-are-not-located-in-directories-below-the-root/17217041#17217041

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in the Sphinx documentation section [TOC Tree](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html).

In your `index.rst`, use the `toctree` directive:

```
Project Awesome
===============

Welcome to the Project Awesome docs.

.. toctree::
   :glob:
   :maxdepth: 2

   docs/*
   new_starter/*
   subject_guides/*
```

The above uses "globbing", but you can explicitly order the files using their names instead of globbing.

Comment: I tried that. It requires a ``:glob: `` by the way. I still have the problem that the side bar doesn't load up properly.

Comment: What do you expect and observe? What is "properly"? It could be a theme issue.

Comment: I'm using the ``readthedocs`` theme. The side bar wasn't updating itself and showing lower levels as I navigate through the docs. However, I did find a fix: I deleted the build files and ran `make html` again. It's working now :)

Comment: Ah, yes. Sphinx uses a cache and rebuilds only the changed files. `make clean html` instead of `make html` should also take "clean" the cache.