# Sphinx: different relative paths to same figure possible?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am new to Sphinx and would like to show the same figure in two different `*.rst` files.

The first *.rst file `"lower.rst"` is on the same level as the "figures" folder and I am including a figure in it like this:

```
.. figure:: figures/figure1.png
```

The second *.rst file `"higher.rst`", is several levels higher than lower.rst. In fact, I am including lower.rst in higher.rst like this:

```
.. include:: relative/path/to/lower.rst.
```

Unfortunately, in the `higher.rst`, the figures from lower.rst are not displayed:

```
"image file not readable" error.
```

`higher.rst` looks in the current directory for the figure instead of pointing to the original lower directory.

This question is sort-of addressed here: [Can sphinx link to documents that are not located in directories below the root document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199233/can-sphinx-link-to-documents-that-are-not-located-in-directories-below-the-root), but I still do not understand how to resolve my problem with the information given there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your figures in a directory at the root level, and change your markup to find them relative to the root using a leading `/`.

```
.. figure:: /_static/figure1.png
```

Now from the higher level file, you should be able to include the lower, and both files should display the image.

Comment: One follow-up question, though: Is there a way to avoid the duplicate label warning for the figures?

Comment: I assume your included file is read as a regular reST document since it matches a value in `source_suffix`. You can either change the suffix (for example, `my_included_file.inc`) or add a pattern matching it to `exclude_patterns` in your `conf.py`.

Comment: yes, my included files are regular *.rst files. When changing the suffix, however, then the lower *.rst file is not included in the toctree anymore:

`WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'/path/to/file/file_name'`.

So, as a quick, but maybe not-so-clean hack, I could copy the *rst file as an *inc file and put that one in the include path?

Comment: Not sure how an exclude pattern would look like for two identical documents that are included in the toctree, but have different suffixes?

Comment: In my last comment, I should have said "same suffixes"

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, `exclude.rst` and `exclude.inc` could be excluded by the pattern `exclude.*`

Comment: Hmm. I have a lot of files that are at the lower path locations, which I want to also have at the top level path locations with the include statement. I can certainly put every single file name into the exclude pattern (which is what the `exclude.*` does: `exclude_patterns=[exclude.*]`, correct?) but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do this? If I exclude both the `*.rst` and the `*.inc` files (which is what `exclude.*` also does, correct?), then none of them will be recognizable for the toctree? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Are you suggesting then that it is a good solution to have a copy of each `*rst` file as `*inc` file? But if I choose to only exclude one of them `exclude_patterns=[*.rst]` or `exclude_patterns=[*.inc]` will the excluded file then be recognized in the toctree? - I am guessing not.

Comment: More examples are in the [documentation for exclude_patterns](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-exclude_patterns).