# Is it possible to include external rst files in my documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm building a documentation for a platform that includes modules. I would like to let the documentations live in these modules repositories and include them in the "master" doc with the include command.

I tried the following :

```
.. include:: https://github.com/12rambau/sepal_ui_template/blob/master/doc/en.rst
```

But nothing was added to the file

Is it possible to use absolute link in `include`command ?

Comment: As it can be security blackhole, I doubt whether that directive accepts a URL like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main objective is not to use the `include` command but to avoid code ducplication and use a file that is available on the web. based on [@Steve piercy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214933/steve-piercy) answer I came up with this solution :

In the `conf.py` file I copy the content of the file from github

> be careful and use the `raw.githubusercontent.com` link to avoid importing html

```py
# [...]
# -- Copy the modules documentation ------------------------------------------

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/12rambau/sepal_ui_template/master/doc/en.rst",
    "modules/sepal_ui_template.rst"
)
```

after that the file is created under `modules/sepal_ui_template.rst` in my documentation and I can safely access it.

It will be download again every time I rebuild my documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No. A fully qualified URL is not relative to the document. According to the docs for the [`include` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include):

> The directive argument is the path to the file to be included, relative to the document containing the directive.

There are alternatives, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199233/can-sphinx-link-to-documents-that-are-not-located-in-directories-below-the-root).