# Generate sphinx documentation of only rst files from different directory (don't have any code in app)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Project structure

```
App
├───2023
│    ├───JULLY
│    │   ├───WEEK26.rst
│    │   └───WEEK27.rst
│    └───JUNE
│        └───WEEK25.rst
├───2022
│    ├───JULLY
│    │   ├───WEEK26.rst
│    │   └───WEEK27.rst
│    └───JUNE
│        └───WEEK25.rst
Doc
├───conf.py
├───modules.rst
├───index.rst
```

how can i reference automatically all folders and in recursive fashion in index.rst

I need to Display data in following format on HTML

```
2023
    JAN
        WEEK 1
        WEEK 2
        WEEK 3
        WEEK 4
    FEB
        WEEK 5
        WEEK 6
        WEEK 7
        WEEK 8
    MARCH
    APRIL

2023
    JAN
        WEEK 1
        WEEK 2
        WEEK 3
        WEEK 4
    
    FEB
        WEEK 5
        WEEK 6
        WEEK 7
        WEEK 8
    MARCH
    APRIL
```

How can achieve same structure in index.rst file without hard-coding whenever new file come in App i need to update same as it is in index.rst

I Tried

```
Documentation Sections
======================

   .. toctree::
      :maxdepth: 2
      :glob:

      ../app/2023/JUNE/*.rst
```

ERROR

```
WARNING: toctree glob pattern '../app/2023/JUNE/*.rst' didn't match any documents
```

Comment: @mzjn I have updated problem statement

Comment: The `toctree` directive accepts wildcards (with the `:glob:` option). Does this help? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

Comment: yes but no luck

Comment: @mzjn sorry but i tried different pattern example i have added in  problem statement

Comment: `toctree` can include files in the current folder (and below). But using `../` to go one level up does not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10199233/407651, https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/701 and https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/11462

Comment: You could use a symlink in your docs directory that points to the target outside of the docs directory.