# Can I describe global alias in rst file for sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to describe an alias with the index.rst file. Then I want to use, this alias other rst files. Is it possible?

eg.

in index.rst file:

```
.. |n1| image:: /_static/Number1.png
   :width: 64px
```

Then I want use this alias for example in page1.rst, page2.rst files.

```
|n1| some texts.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sphinx import parent dir rst file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550659/sphinx-import-parent-dir-rst-file)

Comment: You can use `rst_epilog`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10042061/407651.